# I need help fixing my screen resolution

Tags: video, display-resolution

Newbie Ubuntu user here, currently running 18.04. I haven't had any issues with the kernel until now.

I had to unplug and move my PC out of the room whilst cleaning, and when I plugged everything back in and booted it up, the desktop, login screen and such were all zoomed in, as if I was set to a resolution of 640 x 480. I tried going into the resolutions option menu, but the drop-down has nothing in it. I assumed my video cards needed an update, but every attempt has resulted in a "command not found" output from the terminal. What am I doing wrong?
[image: This is what it looks like]

Edit: To clarify, all that I have done was the following: I shut down my PC, unplug it following its complete shutdown, plug everything back in and turn it on. It started with the 640 x 480 resolution on its own, with seemingly no user input. I made no changes to the system before this procedure, and in an attempt to fix it, I entered the following command line into the terminal

```
sudo apt-get-update
```

Which resulted in an output of

```
apt-get-update: command not found [like this][2]
```

Comment: I can login, no problems there. I simply thought that a visual aid would assist, and the login screen was the first thing I saw.

Will do, and apologies about the missing information. Still new to all of this.

Comment: After login, you can open "Display & screen" and try to change resolution.

Comment: I gave that a try, but unfortunately the options in the dropdown box were completely missing.

Comment: The *command not found* message is correct, you're not using valid commands (the space is a delimiter and cannot be replaced by a "-")

Comment: How would I go about ordering the terminal to update my drivers, then?

Comment: `sudo apt-get-update` is not a valid command.  You should use `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` to complete system updates.  For these two commands, you can also use `apt-get` instaed of `apt`, but `apt` is more user friendly.  Please let us know if this helps resolve your issue

Comment: It did, thank you. Turns out that there were some drivers that were out of date and needed upgrades, and this solved it.

Comment: Consider posting your solution below.  You can even come back later and accept it for more reputation. The whole purpose of AskUbuntu is to build the biggest collection of questions and answers about Ubuntu.  Posting and accepting your answer will help any future visitors that come looking for an answer to your same question.

Comment: Apologies about the late reply. I will do so, and thank you.